# How to understand this kind of function declaration: `=> .. => .. => ..`?

Tags: scala

I see this scala function declaration in somewhere:

```
def test(f: => String => Result[AnyContent] => Result) = ...
```

I never saw this kind of function: `=> ... => ... => ...`, how to understand it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`String => Result[AnyContent] => Result` desugars to `Function1[String, Function1[Result[AnyContent], Result]]`.   It's helpful to read it as:  `=> String => (Result[AnyContent] => Result])`.  That is, a function that takes a `=> String` returns a function `Result[AnyContent] => Result` (also known as curried function).

`=> A` is a by-name parameter of type `A`. So `=> String => Result[AnyContent] => Result` indicates that `test` takes an argument of type `String => Result[AnyContent] => Result` by-name. Learn more about by-name parameters [here](http://daily-scala.blogspot.in/2009/12/by-name-parameter-to-function.html).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a function is a normal data type. Functions can return functions.

```
f: => String => Result[AnyContent] => Result
```

Is the same as

String => ( Result[AnyContent] => Result )

This is just a function from `String` returning a function from `Result[AnyContent]` to `Result`.

`f: =>` is a by name parameter as explained by Josh in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks. Posting answers with a smart phone from a playground while watching your son may be a bad idea ;-)

Comment: @Jan: You're on Stack Overflow whilst you're supposed to be watching your son?!

Comment: Jan, you are mistaken about this taking a `Unit` as the first parameter.  If that were the case, it would start with `() => String => ...` .  Instead, that first, unpreceded `=>` actually means that the parameter is passed by name (basically, that it isn't evaluated until it is used—and _every_ time that it is used).

Comment: @Jan, yes, it's a bad idea. Your son deserves your full attention. :-)

Comment: Thanks Destin. I changed the answer (added the by name parameter). I always thought that `() =>`is more or less the same as `Unit) =>`.